# Phone calender is not synchronizing with Facebook calendar

Tags: calendars, facebook

I linked my windows phone calender to my Outlook.com account. I then did a synchronize with my phone. This account Outlook account is also linked with Facebook, and because of that all the birthday notifications from Facebook are there in my phone calender. If I add a new friend on Facebook, their birthdays are not sync'd to my calender, even after manually trying to sync. How can I get my Facebook birthday calendar to sync to my phone?

Comment: When you say outlook, do you mean the Desktop version of Outlook, or do you mean the web version at http://outlook.com/ ?

Comment: the web version @RowlandShaw

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution after browsing a little:

1. every time you add a new friend to Facebook in order to synchronize there birth date to over calendar we need to export events and birth dates to outlook first
2. then have to synchronize over phone with outlook account as told by @karancan

note: for exporting events to outlook

1. go to event page
2. click export button to export events

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar situation whereby there is a lag (sometimes a few hours, other time a few days) where some information from Facebook doesn't sync to my phone's `People Hub`.

You should be able to force a manual sync by follow these steps:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Under `System`, pick `emails+accounts`
3. For the account that isn't up to date, tap and hold it until you see a menu appear where one of the options is `Sync`

Hope this helps.

Comment: dude i m done with this thing but actually it gonna synchronize the contact and stuff from Facebook but for calender which is directly into the outlook account don't have a way to synchronize that and even the outlook account is not having the birth day's of the newly added friends on it

Answer (score 0):

One of the work around I have done is to sync your facebook account to live account. And get all the birthday reminders of your friends from hotmail added to your calendar.

Answer (score -2):

This Can Help You To Sync Birthdays To Calender

http://windowsphonefanboy.blogspot.in/2013/09/tutorial-how-to-sync-facebook-birthdays.html

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer a little bit. Link only answers are not very useful.